# How is the VM created when using packstack all-in-one to install openstack in one machine?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, openstack, openstack-nova

I installed openstack all nodes in one machine (CentOS7) with cmds:

1. yum install -y openstack-packstack
2. packstack --allinone --provision-demo=n
3. Edit libvirt section in /etc/nova/nova.conf----> **virt_type=kvm**
4. systemctl enable libvirtd openstack-nova-compute
5. systemctl restart libvirtd openstack-nova-compute
6. systemctl status libvirtd openstack-nova-compute
7. systemctl restart libvirtd openstack-nova-compute

As we know, openstack its self cannot create VM, it has to invoke hypervisor to create VM, but when i use packstack all-in-one to install openstack, i want to know how is the VM created, i didn't install any hypervisors(like KVM, Xen) in my machine, why the VM can be created, it is unreasonable.

Comment: It looks like you installed a hypervisor -- you're explicitly enabling `libvirtd`, which manages virtualized guests using `qemu`.

Comment: @larsks Thanks buddy.  1. Do you mean libvirtd is embeded in centos, user no need to install that package by using yum, But just need to enable to make it work? 2. I tried to type "virt-install" or "virt-manager" but those doesn't work, so i thought no kvm hypervisor is installed. So my 2nd question is the libvirt or qemu is another way of kvm hypervisor?

Comment: libvirtd is probably installed by packstack. libvirt manages qemu. qemu can take advantage of kvm, if present, for accelerated virtualization.

Comment: Did you miss something in the [directions](https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/)? At the end it states: "Once the process is complete, you can log in to the OpenStack web interface Horizon by going to `http://$YOURIP/dashboard`. The user name is `admin`. The password can be found in the file `keystonerc_admin` in the `/root` directory of the control node."